# OAuth authentication support for Office 365 IMAP access

Tags: office365

I'm trying to figure out what the current situation is with IMAP authentication for Office 365/outlook.com IMAP access. This [MS article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/) seems to suggest regular password authentication is going to be disabled in October but MS is working on adding OAuth support now. Does that really mean there is a deadline to switchover to OAuth but OAuth isn't available yet?

I found [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dn440163) describing using Live credentials but it looks like that approach may be deprecated. Is there something similar to this [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) that explains what is supported MS IMAP access (if you can't tell I'm not an O365 user, just trying to update an integration).